# Problem importing sqlite into Postgres (with PostGis) using ogr2ogr

Tags: postgis, ogr2ogr, postgis-2.0, sqlite

I am trying to import a very large sqlite file into Postgres SQL 9.3.

The first tool I tried to use was OGR2GUI (http://www.ogr2gui.ca/). The 64 Bit version does nothing, whilst the 32 bit version says

- unable to open ogr2ogr !

I have tried running org2ogr from the command line too, I have tried:

```
ogr2ogr --config SQLITE_LIST_ALL_TABLES YES -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"dbname='mydatabaseName' active_schema=myschema schemas=public host='localhost' port='myportnumber' user='myusername' password='mypassword' " -overwrite -lco SCHEMA=myschema -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=geometry -lco SPATIAL_INDEX=YES myfilename.sqlite  myfilename

ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"dbname=mydatabaseName" myfilename.sqlite myfilename

ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL PG:"host=localhost user=myusername password=mypassword dbname=mydatabaseName" -lco LAUNDER="YES" myfilename.sqlite -skipfailures
```

And various iterations on these, each time I get:

```
Unable to open datasource'myfilename.sqlite' with the following drivers
  -> ESRI Shapefile
  -> MapInfo File
  -> UK .NTF
  -> SDTS
  -> TIGER
  -> S57
  -> DGN
  -> VRT
  -> REC
  -> Memory
  -> BNA
  -> CSV
  -> GML
  -> GPX
  -> KML
  -> GeoJSON
  -> GMT
  -> WAsP
  -> PostgreSQL
  -> PCIDSK
  -> OpenFileGDB
  -> XPlane
  -> AVCBin
  -> AVCE00
  -> DXF
  -> Geoconcept
  -> GeoRSS
  -> GPSTrackMaker
  -> PGDump
  -> GPSBabel
  -> SUA
  -> OpenAir
  -> PDS
  -> HTF
  -> AeronavFAA
 -> EDIGEO
 -> SVG
 -> Idrisi
 -> ARCGEN
 -> SEGUKOOA
 -> SEGY
 -> PDF
 -> SXF
```

Of course sqlite is not on this list, but how can I add it?

I have tried running osgeo set-up, but there is no option I can find to add it.

Comment: i suppose that you are using Windows. In that case you can use the binaries from http://gisinternals.com/sdk. They are compiled with SQLite and Spatialite.

Comment: Thanks, I am having a look, but I have not added binaries before, is there a guide anywhere for adding new binaries to OGR2OGR?

Comment: Ogr2ogr is a compiled binary itself and the gisinternals binaries include ogr2ogr. Use them as ís and you should be fine. With OSGeo4W setup sqlite and spatialite libraries are selected from the "lib" part of advanced setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Issue was resolved with a fresh installation of OSGeo